# Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION - pointer referencing

Tags: c++, pointers, exception

I am just starting up some C++ (that is after 10 years of JAVA!). I am following examples from Stroupstrup book.

I am put together the following code segments from his book.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

map<string, int>histogram;
void record (const string &s)
{
    histogram[s]++; //record frequency of "s"
    cout<<"recorded:"<<s<<" occurence = "<<histogram[s]<<"\n";
}

void print (const pair<const string, int>& r)
{
    cout<<r.first<<' '<<r.second<<'\n';
}

bool gt_42(const pair<const string, int>& r)
{
    return r.second>42;
}

void f(map<string, int>& m)
{
    typedef map<string, int>::const_iterator MI;
    MI i = find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), gt_42);
    cout<<i->first<<' '<<i->second;
}

int main () {
    istream_iterator<string> ii(cin);
    istream_iterator<string> eos;
    cout<<"input end\n";

    for_each(ii, eos, record);

    //typedef pair <string, int> String_Int_Pair;
    //histogram.insert(String_Int_Pair("42", 1));
    //histogram.insert(String_Int_Pair("44", 1));


    //for_each(histogram.begin(), histogram.end(), print);
    f(histogram);

}
```

I get an error - Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION, I think in the referencing i->first, i->second, I guess. Can someone help me out find out what the issue might be. Also if you can suggest some alternate C++ forums that will be helpful as well.

Answer (score 3):

In your `void f(map<string, int>& m)` function you do not check whether you actually found the element that you are looking for, .e.g:

```
void f(map<string, int>& m)
{
    typedef map<string, int>::const_iterator MI;
    MI i = find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), gt_42);
    if(i != m.end())
       cout<<i->first<<' '<<i->second;
    else
       cout << "Not Found" << endl;
}
```

Error probably occures when you are accesing `i->first` when `i` points **"past the end"** of your map container.

Comment: Sorry I didn't pay enough attention to return r.second>42 meaning when count>41 and not inputno.>42.  I just was careless to read the algorithm properly.  Sorry about that.  Thanks for your reply, sirgeorge.